# How to INVERT SCROLLING DIRECTION on trackpad in Raspbian Stretch?

Tags: raspbian-stretch

I would like to **invert the scrolling direction** so that when I scroll down (using two fingers in a downward direction) on my trackpad, the page also moves *down* (i.e. to content lower down).

I did this in Raspbian Jessie previously like [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1141610#p1141610) by editing the **10-evdev.conf** file in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/`.

However, Raspbian Stretch (9.x) uses **libinput** rather than evdev so the method above doesn't work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've figured it out!

The scrolling direction is determined by **libinput** - see [here](http://jlk.fjfi.cvut.cz/arch/manpages/man/libinput.4).

Navigate to the **40-libinput.conf** file in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d` and change the first section as follows:

```
# Match on all types of devices but tablet devices and joysticks
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput pointer catchall"
        MatchIsPointer "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
        Option "NaturalScrolling" "true" #ADD THIS LINE
EndSection
```

Comment: You will have to use `sudo nano 40-libinput.conf` to edit the file.

Comment: Also needs a reboot after adding the option line.